# Binary Search using Data Sets

Tags: java, dataset, binary-search

I need help returning specific data in one of these sets (dataset 3). I have my code below with Scanner imported:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] list, int key) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = list.length - 1;

    while (high >= low) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (key < list[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else if (key == list[mid])
            return mid;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }

    return -low - 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int set = in.nextInt();
    int key = in.nextInt();
    int[][] datasets = { 
            {  },
            {   1,   2,   3,   5,   8,  13,  21,  34,  55, 89 },
            { -81, -72, -63, -54, -45, -36, -27, -18,  -9,  0 },
            {  21,  34,  72, -63,   8,   5, -13, -27, -18,  1,  0,  2 }
    };

    System.out.println("Searching for key " + key + 
                       " in data set "      + set +
                       " returned "         + binarySearch(datasets[set], key));
}
```

}

I need to **return 7** for **key = 5** and **set = 3**.

Expected Output: "Searching for key 5 in data set 3 returned 7"

Current Output: "Searching for key 5 in data set 3 returned -1"

---

I also need to **return 4** for **key = 0** and **set = 3**.

Expected Output: "Searching for key 0 in data set 3 returned 4"

Current Output: "Searching for key 0 in data set 3 returned -1"

---

Am I supposed to write a statement somewhere to remedy this problem or just change the numbers in dataset 3?

Comment: Binary search works when the data are already sorted.  Your data are not sorted.

Comment: @rgettman so I just have to put it in ascending order? Update: that worked, thank you!